# Trying to print lines from text file based on substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that there are 5 lines in *Romeo and Juliet* play that contains both of the words 'Juliet' and 'Romeo' in one line. I am trying to print the lines from the *Romeo and Juliet* play that has the  words 'Juliet' and 'Romeo'.

So far, I tried:

```
pattern = 'Romeo and Juliet'
matching_lines = [line for line in open('Romeo and Juliet.txt').readlines() if pattern in line]
print(matching_lines)
```

but it only prints:

```
['Romeo and Juliet\n']
```

instead of lines from the play that has both the word 'Romeo' and the word 'Juliet'.

Comment: @FatihAkici edited my answer to cover all scenarios would you have a look at it .

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks for the text `Romeo and Juliet`, but this wouldn’t match `Juliet and Romeo` for example. Try `if ‘Romeo’ in line and ‘Juliet’ in line`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this link to download the play text [Romeo and Juliet](http://www.southchurchschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Romeo-Juliet.pdf)

```
# load the whole play text 
with open ('Romeo and Juliet.txt')as f:
    play_text = list(map(str.strip,f.readlines()))


#if you want the match the exact sentence or 'Romeo and Juliet' in each line 
pattern = 'Romeo and Juliet'
matching_lines = [line for line in play_text if pattern in line]
print('matching pattern' ,matching_lines)

#if you want to look for the word 'Romeo' and the word 'Juliet' in each line not nessaserly bond to each other but exist in the same line
matching_words = [line for line in play_text if 'romeo' in line.lower() and 'juliet' in line.lower()]
print('matching words' ,matching_words)
```

**output :**

```
matching pattern ['Romeo and Juliet', '1.5.48 Romeo and Juliet fall in love at first sight', '3.5.1 Romeo and Juliet wake as he must leave for Mantua']
matching words ['Romeo and Juliet', 'FRIAR LAWRENCE.......Franciscan who marries ROMEO & JULIET', 'ROMEO [seeing Juliet; to a Servant 2 ] 1.5.48', "ROMEO [taking Juliet's hand] (a sonnet starts here) 1.5.104", "[Outside Juliet's balcony. ROMEO]", 'Is father, mother, Tybalt, Romeo, Juliet, is like saying', "[Juliet's bedroom, dawn. ROMEO & JULIET]", 'And Romeo dead, and Juliet, dead before,', 'Romeo, there dead, was husband to that Juliet, 5.3.240', 'Than this of Juliet and her Romeo.', '1.5.48 Romeo and Juliet fall in love at first sight', '1.5.104 
Romeo & Juliet talk and kiss, then learn they are enemies', '2.2.1 Romeo & Juliet exchange vows of love and plan to marry (balcony scene)', '2.3.1 Friar agrees to marry Romeo & Juliet', '2.6.1 Friar, Romeo & Juliet meet to be married', '3.2.41 Nurse tells Juliet Romeo killed Tybalt and is now banished', '3.3.156 They plan for Romeo to visit Juliet then flee to Mantua', '3.5.1 Romeo and Juliet wake as he must leave for Mantua', "3.5.65 Juliet's mother tries to comfort her by cursing Romeo", '5.1.1 Romeo hears Juliet is dead; he plans to die by her side', '5.3.84 Romeo finds Juliet and drinks the poison', "5.3.121 Friar arrives; Juliet wakes and sees Romeo's body; Friar flees"]
```

Comment: In general, you should use `.casefold()` for case-insensitive comparisons. It probably isn’t necessary here, since we already know which words we’re going to be comparing, in what alphabet, etc. but it’s something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```py
with open('play_file.txt', 'r') as play_file:
    for line in play_file:
        if 'Romeo' in line and 'Juliet' in line:
            print(line)
```